# How to save a 2d associative array in csv without loops?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 2 dimentional associative array as below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

stateList = ['0_0_0', '0_0_1', '0_0_2', '0_0_3']
toState          = { state : 0  for state in stateList}
transitionCounter = { state : toState.copy()  for state in stateList}

transitionCounter['0_0_0']['0_0_2'] = 1
transitionCounter['0_0_0']['0_0_0'] = 10
transitionCounter['0_0_3']['0_0_2'] = 4

transitionCounter['0_0_1']['0_0_2'] = 5
transitionCounter['0_0_3']['0_0_1'] = 7

print(transitionCounter)
```

But, now i wish to save it in .csv file. So, that its final format should be like this:

[image]

I have tried the below code:

```
stateColumn = ['0_0_0', '0_0_1', '0_0_2', '0_0_3']
dt = pd.DataFrame(columns=stateColumn)
dt["States"] = ['0_0_0', '0_0_1', '0_0_2', '0_0_3']

print(dt)

for fromState in stateList:
    for toState in stateList:
        dt[dt["States"] == fromState,toState] = transitionCounter[fromState][toState]
```

But it complains with the below error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a `DataFrame` from a dictionary you can simply use:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame(transitionCounter).T
```

Result:

```
       0_0_0  0_0_1  0_0_2  0_0_3
0_0_0     10      0      1      0
0_0_1      0      0      5      0
0_0_2      0      0      0      0
0_0_3      0      7      4      0
```

To save a data set as csv file you can use the function [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
dt.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

To fix the error in the `for` loop you need to add the attribute `loc`:

```
for fromState in stateList:
    for toState in stateList:
        dt.loc[dt["States"] == fromState,toState] = transitionCounter[fromState][toState]
```

Comment: it gives me a `.csv` file but the numbers inside it is not accurate. Right?

Comment: @Jeff I didn't get the question. I think you need to add a file name.

Comment: When i follow your solution, the numbers inside the entries are are wrong. 
For example `dt["0_0_2","0_0_0"]` must be `null` meanwhile your solution gives `1` which is wrong. Please find the image which i added to my question. this is a desired output.

Comment: @ Ok. I see. You need to transpose the dataframe. See my edited answer. Need to add `.T` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can write arrays to `.csv`file with `csv.writer(...)`.

For example:

```py
...
import csv

...

with open("new_file.csv","w+") as file:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(file,delimiter=',')
    csvWriter.writerows(transitionCounter)
```

Comment: unfortunately, the output is not true